# Process feeds simultaneously

Tags: php, feed

I am developing a vertical search engine.  When a users searches for an item, our site loads numerous feeds from various markets.  Unfortunately, it takes a long time to load, parse, and order the contents of the feed quickly and the user experiences some delay.  I cannot save these feeds in the db nor can I cache them because the contents of the feeds are constantly changing.

Is there a way that I can process mutliple feeds at the same time at the same time in PHP? Should I use popen or it there a better php parallel processing method?

Thanks!

Russ

Answer (score 1):

If you are using curl to fetch the feeds, you could take a look at the function [`curl_multi_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-exec.php), which allows to do several HTTP requests in parallel.

*(The given example is too long to be copied here.)*

That would at least allow you to spend less time fetching the feeds...

Considering you server is doing almost nothing when it's waiting for the HTTP request to end, parallelizing those wouldn't harm, I guess.

Parallelizing parsing of those feeds, on the other hand, might do some damages, if it's a CPU-intensive operation (might be, if it's XML parsing and all that).

As a sidenote : is it **really** not possible to cache some of this data ? Event if it's only for a couple of minutes ?

Using a cron job to fetch the most often used data and store it in cache, for instance, might help a lot...

And I believe a website responding **fast** is more important to the users than really really upto date at the second results... If your site doesn't respond, they'll go somewhere else !

Answer (score 0):

I agree, people will forgive the caching far sooner than they will forgive a sluggish response time. Just recache every couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to setup a results page that executes multiple simultaneous requests against the server via JavaScript. You can accomplish this with a simple AJAX request and then inject the returned data into the DOM once it's finished loading. PHP doesn't have any support for threading, currently. Parallelizing the requests is the only solution at the moment.

Here's some examples using jQuery to load remote data from a website and inject it into the DOM:
http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/load#urldatacallback